# Node.JS | mysql_fetch_array/assoc?

Tags: node.js

How would I use mysql_fetch_array/assoc in Node.JS? I mean in PHP it's really simple and all you have to do is

```
mysql_fetch_array();
```

or/and

```
mysql_fetch_assoc();
```

and that's it.

How would I do this in Node.JS?
An simple INSERT query is pretty simple as I'd just do something like:

```
var query = connection.query("INSERT INTO test SET number=1337");
console.log(query.sql);
```

(which works fine by the way) but I'm not sure how I would do mysql_fetch_array/assoc in Node.JS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the library you're using?

Comment: @SLaks Couldn't find anything about fetching array/assoc.

Comment: It doesn't do that; it just gives you an array of rows.

Comment: @SLaks Yeah I noticed now when I changed some stuff, that it gives me an array of rows. Now I just got to figure out how to read them.
How would I read each value? (I.E ID and Name)

Comment: With a for loop.  Use `console.log` or a debugger to see what's in the array.

Comment: @SLaks - Well how would it know how many it found/selected for the for-loop?

Comment: With the `length` property, just like any other array.